# Passenger with Rails Action cable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger, actioncable, ruby-2.5

I tried to deploy on production server Rails with actioncable (5.1.5) according to this tutorial
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/action_cable_integration , on the same host and port, under a sub-URI

But i've got 404 on my /cable url, no errors in production.log

Have tried in application.rb

```
config.action_cable.mount_path = '/cable'
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['mydomen.com']
```

no success.

Anyone have experience with this versions of passenger/rails?

```
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
nginx version: nginx/1.12.2
Phusion Passenger 5.1.12
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: Have you changed routes.rb file to incude the route?

Comment: @GorillaApe i changed, yes, ```mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'``` Also tried to deploy to standalone server. Actually action cable works on `/cable` path, but only without nginx passenger `location /cable` config. I presume it works with limited connection number. Maybe i am missing something. Can't figure it out

Comment: I cannot guess what is happening since I need full config. However the only error i see is that you have  config.action_cable.mount_path = '/websocket'  and you use /cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.

I have the nginx config generated by cloud66.com. They forgot to put `passenger_enabled on;` to ssl server section, adding this resolved the problem.